# How do I say that something is partly new in the form of a premodifier?

Tags: modifiers, noun-phrases

If I want to premodify a noun by saying that it is partly new, how do I do this? Neither of the following gets more than one or two hits on Google, and no hits at all on Ngrams, so I suspect they aren't very good solutions, but what can I say instead?

> is a partly new model

> is a partially new model

Comment: Your Google search might have been too restrictive. Searching "a partly new" and "a partially new" (as exact phrases) yields tens of thousands of hits for each. Ngrams also seems to provide plenty of results.

Comment: You haven't provided a *specific* usage context, or the *exact* meaning you want, but I suggest that in most contexts the most natural way to convey "based on an existing model, but with some new elements" is to say it's ***an updated model***. Or if you're working in the advertising department of the company that makes it, it's the ***new, improved model***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "An updated model" is perfect for my purposes! Thank you!!

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Yes, I only searched for strings with a head noun...

Answer (score 1):

How about

> It is a new model in part
> or
> Part of it is a new model
> or
> Parts of it are a new model

Comment: Thank you! These are not premodifier solutions though, so not quite what I was after. I realise I should have been clerar in my OP though, and said that I realise that I can rephrase, but that I'd like to know if there is a way to say this by means of a premodiefier :)